# Cells in CollectionView are not showing

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a UICollectionView programmatically. This is what I have so far

I also have included UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.collectionView!.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 153/255, green: 204/255, blue: 153/255, alpha: 1)

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false
    self.collectionView!.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    // Register cell classes
    self.collectionView!.register(threadCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
    return 3
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell

    return cell
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.height, height: 50)
}

    class threadCell: UICollectionViewCell{
    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }
    let userName: UILabel = {
        let name = UILabel()
        name.text = "testing"
        name.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        name.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return name

    }()
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }
    func setupViews(){
        backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        addSubview(userName)
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0" : userName]))
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0" : userName]))

    }
}
```

The result should display 3 cells each with a testing label

 The app doesn't crash or show any errors but the cells aren't appearing

Comment: Did you set the delegate and the data source? do you see the background color of the collection view? does the delegate methods get called?

Comment: You are not using your custom cell. At least you have to set the name of the cell in Interface Builder to the custom cell and cast the dequeued cell to the custom cell. And please consider that class and struct names are supposed to start with a capital letter

Comment: How you added collection view to viewcotroller

Answer (score 0):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout
collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath:
IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.**height**, height: 50) }
```

I am not sure but do you really want to set the width of cell by view.frame.height?

Answer (score 0):

You need to confirm `dataSource` and `delegate` in viewDidLoad()-:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.collectionView!.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 153/255, green: 204/255, blue: 153/255, alpha: 1)

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false
    self.collectionView!.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    // Register cell classes
    self.collectionView!.register(threadCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this delegate method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
   return CGSize(width: view.frame.height, height: 50)
}
```

**You are creating collectionViewCell's width equal to view height.**

If you want to know how to create collection view programatically : You can check out the project from below link :

[Explain How to create collection in code with auto-layout.](https://github.com/ashislaha/Learn-iOS/blob/master/01.%20AutoLayout%20by%20Code/Autolayout%20by%20Code/Autolayout%20by%20Code/Controller/HomeCollectionViewController.swift)